# How to make a row with 60% of view port height?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Here is my code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="p-1 vw-100 vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100 border border-primary p-1">
   <div class="row border border-danger h-60 p-1 no-gutters">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0">
     Upper
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row h-40 p-1 no-gutters">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-1">
      Lower 1
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-1"> 
     <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      Lower 2
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>  
  </div>
 </body>
```

I have added h-60 class to the first row.
Why the first row does not extend to 60% of viewport height ?

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and yes it won't work on h-60 because sizing property of bootstrap is given in multiples of 25 i.e (25,50,75,100), this applies to both width and height

refer:- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

```
<div class="row border border-danger h-50 p-1 no-gutters">
```

make the above correction and it will work properly.